# Is the input generic overridden by the default generic? What is the priority of generics?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a situation where I want the type of the value field to be constrained by the type of the Type field.  Please see demo1

```
// demo1 
type PropType<T = any> = { new (...arg: any[]): T } | { (): T };

type InferPropType<T> = T extends PropType<infer R> ? R : never;

type FullProperties<Type> = {
    type: Type;
    value?: InferPropType<Type>;
};

const defineComponent = function <
    TProperties extends Record<string, FullProperties<PropType<string>>>,
>(options: { properties: TProperties }) {};

const test = defineComponent({
    properties: {
        str:{
            type:String,
            value:123, // an error here. happy
        },
        gender0: {
            type: String as PropType<'male' | 'female'>,
            value: 'male', //  or 'female'  expect   ok
        },
        gender1: {
            type: String as PropType<'male' | 'female'>,
            value: 'string', // expect   error ` Type 'string' cannot be assigned to type 'male' | 'female' `
        },
    },
});
```

I want to extract the generic to constrain the value field
I tried the following

```
// demo2
const defineComponent1 = function <
    TProperties extends Record<string, FullProperties<Type>>,
    Type, 
>(options: { properties: TProperties }) {};
const test1 = defineComponent1({
    properties: {
        gender0: {
            type: String as PropType<'male' | 'female'>,
            value: 'male',// Cannot assign type 'number' to type 'never'
        },
    },
});
```

How do you do that?
Is it possible?

@captain-yossarian
There are two more highlights here ,  Can be turned into a？ please see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBABQE4HsoBVowDzrgXjgEMA7CAPgLgG84SYB3ACgDo2ikBzALmLIG0AugEpeeAL5wAPjThNRcCQG5QoSLDgBJEgDMYSZGkyxclQnhgAPMDBIATAM6JUGLNgCWu-XABKlAPy+cLz0AG76KiCq4FhwAGpEADbudkRg7igkuHBWNvZOPjAAxihIdtgOYEienAA0suowvACuJADWJCgMJPWhSc0w-i3tnd31aOmZScYwDkNwrR1dJEJw4uRmNKBwcPxtcJ5wbTAQKDqKgmJ7gjnWto4NWLyeeki+41CTJNNYDrxML28ABlhKtJIFaH1EgN5tpXoZXCYfNI4EDKOJtsFFNdbnkHrRGs8vG9keDMZD+oNeHD9AiZtg-GssYtRiRQBioiASiRKnA7DAdJ4YABhFAAWygmVsYCo2ExQPcNiQSVx9yclWqJE4KJIzTFACNvDJ9SgUIkYKQUfwFUqkjcZDb9ElVjJCiUyhUqjV6o7lYlyLVMQBREjpSCq-KPWC8OluX1JANwKEDXjxxJrQMgHYI-TpWYRh5u0rlDXeuAhsMUTM7chMCYZHm8WhQFy59yzGOtpB5pwAMniSRSaQb2Bz3fbDnRwjgmM7aDb+fwlFoSBgYGaSBIcHrmQcLBb8-H+fEkVA3N5Nl5hH5gvooolUtDTGomIPsCPfy2WZ2cA1TcxP5wIScAAHJ6oabxEE4sYmAAjAATAAzCiAAsACsABsAYAT+yZNHACGISh9RwAA9KROyaHARSWkQRRFDAnwHGALAzt+gE7t8iQzJ+-AAPL6gAVsUMpQc4RhuLQ3xivhpZams5CCDh4jVj+nD3PoAAM-7sT+wEAMpevJYkwTgADkYpJDAZkomZeiWeaZnYbpOx4bwFlWdZtTkegAAW+jwBw8BgAwKBwGKpTwL57icL5ySxWATj+aucAkcKlqGkBG70HYByhmFRCAPj-ymqSp7LCKenJAA)

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve. Please provide several test cases with expected an unexpected behavior with explanation. What do you mean `Hope this is a mistake` ? Do you expect TS to throw compilation error in this place?

Comment: Sorry, this is a problem released through translation software.I reorganized it. I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some tricky validation here.
Consider this example:

```js
type PropType<T extends string> = { new(...arg: any[]): T } | { (): T };

type InferPropType<T> = T extends PropType<infer R> ? R : never;


type Validation<T extends Record<string, { type: unknown, value: unknown }>> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends { type: infer Type }
  ? { type: Type, value: InferPropType<Type> }
  : never
}

const defineComponent = <
  Value extends string,
  Entity extends { type: PropType<Value>, value: Value },
  Properties extends Record<string, Entity>,
  >(options: { properties: Properties & Validation<Properties> }) => { };

const test = defineComponent({
  properties: {
    str: {
      type: String,
      value: 123, // an error here. happy
    },
    gender0: {
      type: String as PropType<'male' | 'female'>,
      value: 'male', //  or 'female'  expect   ok
    },
    gender1: {
      type: String as PropType<'male' | 'female'>,
      value: 'string', // TS will highlight it an an error once you fix first error [value: 123]
    },
  },
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbGOBW)

**`Validation`** - utility type iterates through infered `Properties` property and assures that each value which has `type` property implements this interface `{ type: Type, value: InferPropType<Type> }`.

As you might have noticed `value: 123` is an error but `value: 'string'` is not. No worries. Try to fix first error and TS will highlight `value:"string"` as an error.

If you are interested in function arguments inference and type validation you can check my articles [here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) and [here](https://catchts.com/validators)

Comment: You're amazing. Learn from you

Comment: After reading your article, is it possible to get both validation and literal?

Comment: I m not sure what you mean. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I'm not sure. In order to validate `value` you first need to infer `type`. SInce `value` and `type` are part of the same structure I don't see other way but I'm might be mistaken

Comment: I've recently reorganized the post, see the sample link at the bottom  ‘There are two more highlights here , Can be turned into a？’